# Python Selenium how to interact with a specific button on a web page

Tags: python, html, selenium, button, xpath

Hi i'm trying to interact with this web element in the following link https://www.gurufocus.com/stocks

[Here you can find the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBUUT.png)

I want to set it to 100 so that i can visualize 100 stocks at the time i've tried to interact with it by using the following code

```
wd.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/section[2]/main/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/span/div[2]").click()

wd.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[6]").click()
```

But only the first line works the second line gives me the following error

```
    selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='el-popover-2775']"}
  (Session info: chrome=106.0.5249.119)
```

It is not able to locate it i have also tried with the method find element_by_id but still not able to locate the button that sets the number on 100 [This one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edWvF.png) does anyone has an other solution? Thanks in advance let me know if you need more information i will answer as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can select the dropdown like this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "aio-tabs-button").click()
```

and select 100 like this:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='item' and contains(text(), '100')]").click()
```

However, I'd recommend using the API and a package like requests instead of simulating the browser.

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer can you put an example of how to put all the 82k tickers in a list? I have tried with pandas but it returned error 403 thanks in advance

Comment: i mean with the request module